# Fixing Boolean issues between objects with matching edges/vertices

Tags: modifiers

I'm currently working on a project for 3D printing that involves a bunch of subdivision and multiple parts, and for those who are familiar with 3D printing, usually a solid, single volume mesh is required to avoid issues with printing. I figured using boolean modifiers would work best, but I ran in to some problems.

When using union, my mesh does not properly form into a new, single volume because of edges that are similar

Offending Edges (Second set hasn't been subdivided since applying boolean applies all modifiers from the target)

[image: Set1]
[image: Set2]

What happens

[image: Ew]

I can create the result I need by moving one set of offending vertices, but then the clean edge I needed is destroyed in the process
[image: Kinda There]

I can't join the parts together manually because presubdivide, the subdivision modifier obliterates the edges/shapes I want (yall know how it goes with edge creases)

This happens multiple times throughout the rest of the parts. Is there any way to circumvent this issue, or is the only way to fix it is to manually fix any issues afterwards? I'm fine with doing the manual work (I'd rather not risk a print messing up, as this is going to be a massive multiple piece print so failed prints would be costly), but just wanted to see if anyone knows a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found one way to fix this

1. Duplicate one of the two offending meshes
2. Apply remesh to the new duplicate
3. Separate a part of the mesh that included the offending vertices from the newly remeshed mesh
4. Delete the offending vertices and vertices that overlay with the new piece from the old mesh
5. Stitch together the old mesh and the newly remeshed part

The reason I needed to restitch the old mesh with the remeshed piece is because the remesh destroyed edges and faces that didn't fall along the remesh grid (aka curves and diagonals)

Still looking to see if there are simpler/less destructive ways around this though

Answer (score 0):

Boolean isn't good for 3D printing at all, it often creates a lot of errors. Iam using multiple objects, joint them and after Iam done I use voxel remesh, which makes it one object in topology and solid.